# Ext4 external HDD seems to be 10x faster than usual, can anyone explain this

Tags: hard-drive, format, ext4

i have bought a 1 TB Seagate Usb 3.0 External Harddrive (mechanical) a while ago. I formatted this drive on ext4 because i only was intend to use this drive on linux systems. Now yesterday for example, I copied 1.7 Gigabyte to it, and it took only between 10 and 15 seconds. With any other external HDD i have, this would take at least 5 minutes. My desktop pcs internal harddrives are mechanical too, so none of them all is a SSD. I have this odd highspeed transfer all the time with this particular external HDD. I have checked regulary if the copied data would be really copied, and it is, and it is not corrupted or somekind of. Is this highspeed because i have formatted the drive on ext4 ? I m puzzled about what causes this. Can anyone explain this. I must apologize for asking the question here at this forum, but i could not find any other fitting forum to ask this, for example quora does not allow more than a couple of lines in a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linux is more efficient with the linux file system `ext4` compared to the Microsoft file system NTFS.

But there could be other reasons too for the speed difference.

- The drive's hardware can be faster, including the electronics that connects the drive to the computer.
- There could also be a feature that makes it look faster than it is. The write operation is buffered, and indicates that is has finished, when the program has written to the buffer. But it will take additional time to flush the buffer and finally write to the storage medium.

  You can make the system flush the buffers (this one and also other buffers, if there are data waiting to be written to other drives too). Open a terminal window, run the command

  ```
  sync
  ```

  and wait until the terminal window returns to the prompt.

Comment: no this is the odd thing about it. after writing to this drive i can disconnect it within a few seconds most of the time.

Comment: @BasLamerichs, Well, then you should be happy :-) The combination of `ext4` and a fast drive will make it much faster than your old drives. I have speeds in the same range with my 4 TB HDD drive connected via SATA, and a good USB 3 connection can provide such speed too.